# Can I filter a django model with a python list?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Say I have a model object 'Person' defined, which has a field called 'Name'. And I have a list of people:

```
l = ['Bob','Dave','Jane']
```

I would like to return a list of all Person records where the first name is *not* in the list of names defined in l.

What is the most pythonic way of doing this?

EDIT: After thinking about it, what I really was trying to do is come up with a sub list of l that *wasn't* present in the Person table. Is there an efficient way of doing this? I can think of a few ways, not sure how efficient though.

Comment: It is fine to consider "efficient" but "correct" and "does what I need" come first. This sounds cliche, but the more I learn Python the more that seems to be an aspect of "pythonic". Common practice in C has historically considered both "correct" and "efficient"; since Python constructs are less visibly converted in to their machine translation, the language has been shifting the way I prioritize the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Renaming `l` for readability:

```
names = ['Bob','Dave','Jane']

Person.objects.[exclude][1](Name__[in][2]=names)
```

UPDATE 1: Answer to the second question (in your 'EDIT' paragraph):

```
present = Person.objects.values_list('Name', flat=True)
absent = set(names) - set(present)   
# or, if you prefer named functions to the set operator '-'
absent = set(names).difference(present)
```

Yes, the "right hand side" of difference (but not '-') accepts any iterable (I had to [look it up](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) to confirm).

Comment: This is the right approach, but use `Person.objects.values_list('Name', flat=True')` instead of your list comprehension to get the list of names.

Comment: @daniel, not sure i understand. Can you rewrite msw's example line?

Comment: @msw, actually you didn't need the list comprehension at all with the `flat=True`. Hope you don't mind, I've edited it myself.

Comment: @daniel no worries about the edit but I was getting a list of 1-tuples out. Time to figure what I botched, thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

`Person.objects.exclude(name__in=['Bob','Dave','Jane'])`